# Javascript Jquery div .text assign value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to change some can which depends in jQuery to pure JS and I was wondering how I can translate this one:

```
$("#mydiv .car span").text(myVariable);
```

What would the code above be in pure JS?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#mydiv .car span").textContent = myVariable;`

Comment: Have you done any research how to target elements using selectors and how to change the property? The comment above will work but if you want to learn from it you can read the documentation here: [**.querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)  and [**.textContent()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using **[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) like this:

```
document.querySelector("#mydiv .car span").textContent = myVariable;
```

Or using [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) like this :

```
document.querySelector("#mydiv .car span").innerText = myVariable;
```

[MDN Reference for **`document.querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

Which makes it similar to jQuery with the possibility of using this kind of selector.